# How to Create Calculated Field in Workday with multiple conditions

Tags: calculated-field, workday-api

I'm trying to create a calculated field that returns a numeric score based on Tenure (months) but with multiple conditions. For example, IF an employee is currently active, THEN they receive 5 points. IF they terminated after 12 months THEN 4 points, IF 10-11 months THEN 3 points, IF 7-9 months THEN 2 points, IF 3-6 months THEN 1 point and IF the employee left under 90 days THEN 0 points. I was able to create a calculated field that returns tenure in months. Now I just need to evaluate the expression for the months returned to create a scoring system. Does anyone have any ideas?

I don't know enough about complex calculated fields so I haven't tried anything that's worth noting. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You will end up building an Evaluate Expressing field. I am assuming your "Tenure Length Field" is created on the Worker object, and you also want to receive the score on the Worker object.

1. Create True/False fields on Worker object for every scenario condition: "Tenure Field" >= 12, ("Tenure Field is >= 10 AND Tenure Field <=11"), ("Tenure Field is >= 7 AND Tenure Field <= 9") etc.
2. Your Workday tenant most likely has numeric fields for the number of points (4,3, 2 etc) on the Global business object. If not, you can create them.
3. Create an Evaluate Expression field on Worker object. Create a condition for each scenario by using the True/False fields created in the first step and a corresponding numerical value from the Global object (either existing or created in the second step).

For best practices, start with the condition that is likely to capture more workers than the second and so on - this will insure better performance of your calculated field. So, if you the majority of workers in your tenant has tenure >12 month, start with that condition as the first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I've never created a calculated field before so your advice is a bit confusing. When I select "Evaluate Expression" for the calculate field type, I do not have the option to use True/False in the next option. Are you able to break down the steps in layman terms? Sorry...

Comment: Well, my first step in the comment above says to create "True/False" fields - this is the type of the field you need to create. As I mentioned, create a True/False field for every condition. 
Then check if your Global business object has numeric fields for each score, if not - create them on Global or Worker - those would the type of "numeric constant".

Once done with steps 1 and 2, you can create your Evaluate Expression field using the  True/False conditions and numeric constant. 
BTW, for your Evaluate Expression field select Field Type of Numeric. This is the type it returns.